# how do i put a selected value from a select tag into a mail function?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, select

Im having quite a lot of trouble doing this. At the moment in the email where it should say what has been selected in the select tag it just says Array.

```
    if($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $number_staff = $_POST['amount_people'];
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $number_staff = $_POST['amount_people'];
    mail('myemailaddress', 'Subject',' Amount Of people: '.$_POST['amount_people'].'', $headers);

    }
```

Thats the php.

```
    <form action="staff-mugs.php" method="post">
    Number of staff:
        <select name="amount_people">
            <option value="-- --">-- --</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
                    </form>
```

Thats the html. 
Would be great to get this little problem fixed. 
thanks in advance

Comment: It should have worked. But you can debug this by printing what you have in your $_POST array.

Comment: When i print it 
'print($_POST['amount_people']);'
 it comes up with array.

Comment: are you sure you don't have multiple tag : <select MULTIPLE name="amount_people"> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select can also be multivalue. That's why it always returns an array. You need a loop or you could use radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="amount_people" value="--" checked>--
<input type="radio" name="amount_people" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="amount_people" value="2">2
<input type="radio" name="amount_people" value="3">3 etc.
```

Then your value is in

```
$_POST["amount_people"]
```

"checked" should be there because not returning anything is unpredictable.

If you want the buttons to be in a column, add brs to each line.